# Python Kivy: using variables within classes with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My code is getting quite dense so I'm hoping to simplify it by using variables but it's not working.  Here is the code with a comment near the problem area:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

import pygame
from pygame.locals import*

import random

class RootScreen(ScreenManager):

    pass

class StartScreen(Screen):

    pass

class StartScreen(Screen):

    pass

class LevelsScreen(Screen):

    pass


class LevelOneBedroomScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LevelOneBedroomScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def next_text(self):
        #Here is where I want to use variables
        example_var_a = self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text
        example_var_b = self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text
        if example_var_a == 'a01':
            example_var_b = 'Why is it that no matter how much I sleep, I always wake up tired?'
            example_var_a = 'a02'
        elif example_var_a == 'a02':
            example_var_b = 'But hey, at least it’s the weekend.  What should I do first?'
            example_var_a = 'a03'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03': #Decision time!
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice' 
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c1':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'Do I look like a responsible adult to you?'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text = 'a03c1a'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c1a': #Decision time!  
            self.manager.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice_progress.text = 'a01a'
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'       
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c2':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'Nothing gets your day started like a hearty brownie!'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text = 'a03c2a' 
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c2a': #Time to Move!
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'To the Kitchen!  Post-haste!'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_left_button.text = 'Kitchen'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c3':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'I\'m too tired for this.  Back to sleep it is!'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text = 'a03c3a'
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c3a':
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text = 'Goodnight World!'
            self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text = 'a03cb'             
        elif self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03cb':
            self.manager.current = 'game over'
            self.manager.ids.game_over.ids.game_over_text.text = 'a01'
            self.manager.ids.game_over.ids.game_over_text.text = 'And so you went to sleep.'

    def next_move(self):
        if self.ids.level_one_bedroom_progress.text == 'a03c2a':
            self.manager.current = 'level one kitchen'
```

Here is the .kv:
    #:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

```
<RootScreen>:
    transition: FadeTransition() 
    StartScreen:
        id: start_screen
    LevelsScreen:
        id: levels_screen
    LevelOneBedroomScreen:
        id: level_one_bedroom


<StartScreen>:
    name: 'start'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'start_screen.png'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:     
            source: 'start_screen.png'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint: 1, 1
        Button:
            text: 'Start'
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.3
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5}
            font_size: 70
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'levels' 


<LevelsScreen>:
    name: 'levels'
    BoxLayout:
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            Button:
                text: 'Level 1'
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'level one bedroom'
            Button:
            Button:
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:     
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:     


<LevelOneBedroomScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom'
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: level_one_bedroom_progress
            text: 'a01'
    Image:
        id: level_one_bedroom_image
        source: 'placeholder_background.png'
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Image of Bedroom'
                text_size: self.width, None
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
            Button:
                id: level_one_bedroom_text
                size_hint_y: .32
                text: '*YAWN*'
                color: .5,.2,1,1
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                text_size: self.width, None
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
                on_release: root.next_text()
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .15
            Button:
                id: level_one_bedroom_left_button
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                on_release: root.next_move()
            Button:
                text: 'Home'    
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'levels'         
            Button:
                id: level_one_bedroom_right_button
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
```

When I write the entire thing out without using variables it works fine.  The variables I'm talking about are in the class: LevelOneBedroomScreen, and the variables are: example_var_a, example_var_b.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What variables do you mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for always helping, I have specified the variables at the end of the post and its location.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Are you saying that these variables cannot be used in your other method within the class where you defined the variables?

Comment: @immeeh what is `level one bedroom choice`?

Comment: I think that I see your issue. You are changing the value of the variable, but this does not change the text that you are attempting to change. You will have to specifically Change the value of the text on the widget that you want to alter.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to update example_var_b, and example_var_a if example_var_a meets a certain condition. Then (i’m Assuming) you want to change the text in the Kivy app when you change the value of these variables. That won’t work by only updating the variable because it is not connected to the UI. You will have to specifically change the value of the labels text attribute “level_one_bedroom_progress”

Comment: I see, thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following line:

```
example_var_b = self.ids.level_one_bedroom_text.text
```

you are not assigning the property but the value of it, so after modifying `example_var_b` the text will not be modified.

If you want to make your code more readable then create 2 properties that store the text and progress, and these are assigned to the text of the Label and the Button as I show below:

***.kv**

```
...
<LevelOneBedroomScreen>:
    name: 'level one bedroom'
    level_one_bedroom_progress: "a01" # <--- property
    level_one_bedroom_text: '*YAWN*'  # <--- property
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.level_one_bedroom_progress # <--- set value
    Image:
        id: level_one_bedroom_image
        source: 'placeholder_background.png'
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Image of Bedroom'
                text_size: self.width, None
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
            Button:
                size_hint_y: .32
                text: root.level_one_bedroom_text # <--- set value
                color: .5,.2,1,1
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                text_size: self.width, None
                valign: 'middle'
                halign: 'center'
                on_release: root.next_text()
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .15
            Button:
                id: level_one_bedroom_left_button
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                on_release: root.next_move()
            Button:
                text: 'Home'    
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'levels'         
            Button:
                id: level_one_bedroom_right_button
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
```

***.py**

```
...
class LevelOneBedroomScreen(Screen):
    def next_text(self):
        if self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a01':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'Why is it that no matter how much I sleep, I always wake up tired?'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a02'
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a02':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'But hey, at least it’s the weekend.  What should I do first?'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a03'
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03': #Decision time!
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice' 

        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c1':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'Do I look like a responsible adult to you?'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a03c1a'

        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c1a': #Decision time!  
            self.manager.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice.ids.level_one_bedroom_choice_progress.text = 'a01a'
            self.manager.current = 'level one bedroom choice'       
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c2':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'Nothing gets your day started like a hearty brownie!'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a03c2a' 
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c2a': #Time to Move!
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'To the Kitchen!  Post-haste!'
            self.level_one_bedroom_left_button = 'Kitchen'
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c3':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'I\'m too tired for this.  Back to sleep it is!'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a03c3a'
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c3a':
            self.level_one_bedroom_text = 'Goodnight World!'
            self.level_one_bedroom_progress = 'a03cb'             
        elif self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03cb':
            self.manager.current = 'game over'
            self.manager.ids.game_over.ids.game_over_text.text = 'a01'
            self.manager.ids.game_over.ids.game_over_text.text = 'And so you went to sleep.'

    def next_move(self):
        if self.level_one_bedroom_progress == 'a03c2a':
            self.manager.current = 'level one kitchen' 

...
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you @eyllanesc.  My original code worked, but it was getting increasingly unreadable and this makes it much better so thank you.

Comment: @immeeh 
I recommend you improve your question, for example place an appropriate title and a description focused on your problem but clear, a way to verify that your question is understandable is to read it by another person and understand it. The questions are not just for you but for future askers, and the title is the main filter, do you think someone could find your question with the initial title? if you continue with bad writing you will receive more downvotes, and you will not be able to ask.

Comment: Oh yikes, for some reason I thought i made the title something to do with variables in classes on kivy... i'll change it.. in regards to titles and questions, I do understand that they are not for me, but the problem is I'm not entirely sure what good questions are yet.  I get that I should have all relevant information, clearly state the problem, and try not to have too much extra stuff in it, and so I try but I'm not that great at asking questions yet.  I will try to improve.

Comment: @immeeh 
Your question should talk about your underlying problem, not about possible solutions, that is called [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Check the link for more information.

Comment: @immeeh [cont.] 
I would recommend you use a paragraph to indicate what you want (few lines), another paragraph to indicate your solution, giving information on which you based yourself. Then place a code, but that can be reproduced, that is, those of us who wish to help you do not waste time patching, guessing, etc., but focus on the question. and finally to paragraph that points to a single question. also follow the recommendations indicated in the previous comment.